# Magento 2 - Product is not showing in categories after upgrade Magento 2.2.6 to 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3

[image: please check my screenshot]

I did update Magento version 2.2.6 to 2.3.3 after that product is not showing in categories, I can search product it's showing as well on homepage.

Can you please guide me on this issue?

Comment: version 2.6?? are you sure?

Comment: i was using magento 2.2.6

Answer (score 0):

I have to fetch the same issue so Please, a ***check-In Database View*** is created or not ***If a View*** is not there so ***create view after indexing and flush...***
may your issue resolve...
Happy Coding...